# Why don't I see layout changes on Android device and get unresolved reference error?

Tags: java, android

I am writing my second android app (beginner) having the following problems:

a. When I make changes to my XML (text view/image view), it changes on the android studio design preview. But not on my mobile phone or simulator. I am stuck with Hello from C++.

b. I've recently tried a birthday card application and been getting errors when I add a new text view or image view.

Stuck any help will be appreciated thanks.

I have tried a solution I saw on here; making changes to MainActivity.kt.

```
//  sample_text.text = stringFromJNI() 
//  val sample_text : TextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sample_text) 
TextViewsample_text.text = "Happy Birthday"
//got errors
```

ORIGINAL CODES

My `activity_main` file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
android:text="Happy Birthday Jimmy"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
app:srcCompat="@drawable/androidparty" 
android:id="@+id/imageView"/>

<TextView
android:text="from Osas"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/textView" 
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/> </RelativeLayout>
```

My `mainactivity.kt` file:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Example of a call to a native method
        sample_text.text = stringFromJNI()
    }

    /**
     * A native method that is implemented by the 'native-lib' native library,
     * which is packaged with this application.
     */
    external fun stringFromJNI(): String

    companion object {

        // Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("native-lib")
        }
    }
}
```

Compiler error:

```
build failed    2 s 564 ms
Run build   2 s 405 ms
Load build  41 ms
Configure build 793 ms
Calculate task graph    46 ms
Run tasks   1 s 433 ms
null    
/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/HappyBirthday 
app/src/main/java   
com/example/android/happybirthday/MainActivity.kt   
Unresolved reference: sample_text
```

Here some screenshots after applying the solution I saw here and made changes to mainactivity.kt.

[image: Main activity] [image: Compiler] [image: Mobile simulator] [image: activity_main.xml]

Comment: The layout in your android studio and the screenshot of the layout that you have provided are completely different.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to display or modify the values of any view like setting text in a TextView or changing an image in ImageView then you need to assign id to those views in XML or programmatically.

```
android:layout_id="@+id/give_Some_ID"
```

Now, you need to use your view ID in java file.

```
TextView tv =findViewById(R.id.give_Some_ID);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response- but i am a bit confused because of the tutorial(Udacity) i am using. It says i can make changes from the layout file. It never said anything about making changes to the java file. When i compiled my first code "Hello world", i didnt encounter any error messages. Apart from my mobile simulator showing Hello from C++ and not "Hello world".  So do i assign the ID to the views in the activity main(layout) or under the Java file?

Comment: You assign the id to the View in the layout xml file. Then make reference to that view using that id to access or modify its properties.

Comment: Thanks figured out the problem with my mobile stimulator, at the create andriod page i didnt include create C++ support.